Unable to build element-ios | Cannot find protocol declaration for 'OS_xpc_object'
I am unable to build element-ios project.
I followed all READ-ME instructions but I am still getting these errors:
element-ios-develop/Pods/FLEX/Classes/GlobalStateExplorers/SystemLog/ActivityStreamAPI.h:31:1 Cannot find protocol declaration for 'OS_xpc_object'; did you mean 'OS_sec_object'?

element-ios-develop/Pods/FLEX/Classes/GlobalStateExplorers/SystemLog/ActivityStreamAPI.h:31:1 Reference to 'OS_xpc_object' is ambiguous

element-ios-develop/Pods/FLEX/Classes/GlobalStateExplorers/SystemLog/ActivityStreamAPI.h:31:1 Typedef redefinition with different types ('NSObject<OS_sec_object> *' vs 'NSObject<OS_xpc_object> *')

I am running XCode 15.4 on Mac M2.
My friend which has an Intel is able to build element-ios.
Do you have an idea?
Thanks!
